# Does the function $ \{ x \in G_1 \ : \ x^k = a\} \rightarrow \{ y \in G_2 \ : \ y^k = \phi(a) \}$ have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

So I'm stuck on a problem and I'd like to do more research. But I'm afraid I don't know what to even type into Google to start. The problem is this:

> Let $\phi: G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ be a homomorphism of groups, $a \in G_1$, and $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$. Then show that
>
> $$\begin{align} \{ x \in G_1 \ : \ x^k = a\} &\rightarrow \{ y \in G_2 \ : \ y^k = \phi(a) \}, \\ x &\mapsto \phi(x)\end{align}$$
>
> is well-defined.

This feels to me like the kind of question a knowledgable algebraist would look at and think, "Oh of course! This an example of the well-studied phenomenon ______." I just need a keyword so I can do further research. Does anyone know what to call a function like the one above? Or is this just some special example my professor cooked up?

Thanks in advance!

---

FWIW: I *think* the trick here is that $x$ could have finite order $n$, in which case you can write $x = x^{mn +1}$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. So you have to show that $\phi(x) = \phi(x^{mn+1})$. And then as a frustrated attempted at doing that, I've written down that $\phi(x^{mn+1}) = \phi(x^{mn})\phi(x) =  \phi(e_1)\phi(x) = e_2 \phi(x)$ so that indeed $\phi(x^{mn+1}) = \phi(x)$. But I'm not convinced that's right because I'm essentially just converting $x^{mn+1}$ back to $x$, rather than sending it through $\phi$ first.

Comment: The map $x\mapsto \phi(x)$ should be well-defined in and of itself (you just apply $\phi$ to $x$). I think the task is to check the domain and codomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $M := \{x \in G_1 | x^k = a \} \subseteq G_1$ and $N := \{y \in G_2 | y ^k = \phi(a) \} \subseteq G_2$.

Since $\phi: G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ is a well defined map, we certainly have $\phi(M) \subseteq G_2$.

The problem is to show that $\phi(M) \subseteq N$.

But we get this from basic properties of homomorphisms as follows.

Pick any $x \in M$. Then we have $x^k = a$. Applying $\phi$ to both sides of this equation, we get $\phi(x^k) = \phi(a)$.

Moreover, since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, we have $\phi(x^k) = \phi(x)^k$.

Combining the preceding two equations, we get $\phi(x)^k = \phi(x^k) = \phi(a)$.

But this says that $\phi(x) \in N$.

Since $x \in M$ was arbitrary, we have shown
$$
\forall x \in M: \phi(x) \in N.
$$
Or, in other words
$$
\phi(M) \subseteq N,
$$
which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Dang! I even considered that idea for a moment, but rejected it because every time we've had to show something is well-defined in this class, we've focused on the "If $x_1 = x_2$, then $\phi(x_1) = \phi(x_2)$" aspect. But it sounds like you're saying that because $\phi$ is a homomorphism, that part is already taken care of. And instead we need to focus on making sure the codomain is correct? Anyway, thank you so much for this answer! Extremely clean and easy to follow, and it changed my perspective on the problem. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You can recognise the situation you are used to, when the "$x$" is ambiguous. This typically happens when we are dealing with *sets* 
of elements, e.g. $[x][y] = [xy]$ for residue classes. In your example, it is not the fact that $\phi$ is a homomorphism that makes it well-defined. It's because $x$ is not ambiguous at all. We just take $x$, and apply a function on it – nothing can go wrong.

Comment: This is very helpful. I spent so long looking for a way to make $x$ ambiguous so I could apply the steps I'd learned previously. This ended up being a good problem because it expanded my perspective on what it means to be "well-defined". I thank you for your help!